# Replace ConditionalOnEnabledEndpoint for Spring Boot 2.6.4

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-actuator

I want to migrate old Spring project which is using this dependency:

```
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.condition.ConditionalOnEnabledEndpoint
```

This Class requires import of:

```
'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:2.0.2.RELEASE'
```

I tried to use the latest version:

'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:2.6.4' but `ConditionalOnEnabledEndpoint` is not available. Do you know which class should be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't exist anymore (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.4/api/). In version 2.2.0 it was deprecated in favour of `@ConditionalOnAvailableEndpoint` (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/condition/ConditionalOnEnabledEndpoint.html).

Comment: Thanks, it's safe to replace it right?

Comment: You'll lose the ability to use Spring Boot 2.1 and earlier, but that's it.

Comment: I want to migrate to the latest stable Spring Boot version

Comment: Then it's safe to use `@ConditionalOnAvailableEndpoint` instead of `@ConditionalOnEnabledEndpoint`. I've made that replacement a while ago already, without anything breaking.